# Outbound port open on firewall, how to unblock for PHP?

Tags: php, port, firewall

The goal is to send outbound email from my shared host to Mandrill via SMTP using PHP and I have full cooperation with the host sys admins.

Current situation:

- ✅ PHP can connect to smtp.mandrillapp.com port 443 (used for HTTPS)
- ❌ PHP cannot connect to smtp.mandrillapp.com port 587 (used for SMTP)
- ✅ PHP can connect to portquiz.net port 443 (used for HTTPS)
- ❌ PHP cannot connect to portquiz.net port 587 (used for SMTP)
- ✅ Telnet can connect to smtp.mandrillapp.com port 443
- ✅ Telnet can connect to smtp.mandrillapp.com port 587

Telnet is tested by them logging in as root and running `telnet HOST PORT`. PHP is tested by using the script below.

**What configuration option for PHP could possibly be causing outbound connections on port 587 to be blocked? And how can we reverse that configuration?**

```
<?php
// Test outbound server connections

// https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582167-What-SMTP-ports-can-I-use-
$servers = array(
    array("ssl://www.google.com", 443),
    array("ssl://smtp.mandrillapp.com", 465),
    array("smtp.mandrillapp.com", 25),
    array("smtp.mandrillapp.com", 587),
    array("smtp.mandrillapp.com", 2525),
    array("smtp.mandrillapp.com", 443)
);

foreach ($servers as $server) {
    list($server, $port) = $server;
    echo "<h1>Attempting connect to <tt>$server:$port</tt></h1>\n";
    flush();
    $socket = fsockopen($server, $port, &$errno, &$errstr, 10);
    if(!$socket) {
      echo "<p>ERROR: $server:$portsmtp - $errstr ($errno)</p>\n";
    } else {
      echo "<p>SUCCESS: $server:$port - ok</p>\n";
    }
    flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the error numer?

Comment: You have one check making it to port 587. It's not being blocked going out. You don't actually check anything on port 586.

Comment: @JasonK thanks, I have updated the 586/587 typo in this question

Comment: @PrestonS Error is: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.mandrillapp.com:465 (Connection timed out) in /home/heroanswers/public_html/smtptest.php on line 22
ERROR: ssl://smtp.mandrillapp.com: - Connection timed out (110)

Comment: @FullDecent that error message is not for the port in question, what is the error for port 587?

Comment: @PrestonS sorry, pasted the wrong one... they are all the same

Comment: Very strange, try the 3rd comment from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400733/php-fsockopen-unable-to-connect-connection-timeout-error) (by @artfulrobot) and see if you can connect.  You may have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to block any specific ports using PHP. (Maybe using suhosin, but I've never heard of this option.)

Could you ask your hosting provider if SELinux is enabled? SELinux allows the operating system to deny certain users/processes to bind/connect to a certain port. This could be the reason why they can connect to the SMTP server using telnet as root, but the PHP process under your own user is not able to. I've experienced CentOS servers in which I was unable to connect to port 80 with PHP/Apache, but when I executed curl/wget as root everything went great.

Comment: Apache was having extra restrictions. And it seems they were able to make this exception for me. Thanks!